# How to deploy an Ionic app with CouchDB and PouchDB using Heroku?

Tags: heroku, deployment, ionic2, couchdb, pouchdb

I just followed along with this tutorial to create a Todo list app with user authentication: https://www.joshmorony.com/part-2-creating-a-multiple-user-app-with-ionic-2-pouchdb-couchdb/

The app is built with the Ionic 2 Framework using CouchDB and PouchDB to create a separate database for each user. However, I am totally confused as to how to move this setup from my local machine to a Heroku server.

Can anyone provide a step by step process to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Heroku no longer supports couchdb addon seems it was closed sometime back. For couchdb-pouchdb hosting you can use IBM's cloudant, irish couch or digital ocean.
For my case i setup an ubuntu16.04 droplet on digital ocean, installed and configured couchdb on it. You can check out this [list](http://www.whoishostingthis.com/compare/couchdb/) of couchdb hosting sites. Hope this helps

Comment: So, there is no free tier?